# Prevent bots from crawling dynamic javascript files

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, bots, googlebot, google-crawlers

I need to prevent bots from crawling `.js` files. As you know Google is able to crawl `.js` files. There is only one `.js` file but it will change with new deployments and updates.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/7c2af7d5829e81965805cc932aeacdea8049891f.js?js_resource=true"></script>
```

I want to make sure, since I don't know how to verify this, that this is correct:

```
// robots.txt
Disallow: /*.js$
```

Also, is this the same if the `.js` file served through cdn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# robots.txt
Disallow: /*.js?js_resource
```

This works fine. You can test your robots.txt in Google Search Console AKA Google Webmaster tools.

Answer (score 0):

Globbing and regular expressions are not supported in robot.txt files. From http://www.robotstxt.org:

> Note also that globbing and regular expression are not supported in
>   either the User-agent or Disallow lines. The '*' in the User-agent
>   field is a special value meaning "any robot". Specifically, you cannot
>   have lines like "User-agent: *bot*", "Disallow: /tmp/*" or "Disallow:
>   *.gif".

You should instead move your JavaScript files to a directory that you disallow in the robots file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /hidden-javascript/
```